# How to edit the selected cell on jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I'm using inline editing with jqGrid, but when I select a cell, the cursor is set in the first column of the row, but I'd like to know if there is any way to edit the current cell I have clicked on, instead of the first row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219598/how-to-set-focus-to-cell-which-was-clicked-to-start-inline-edit-in-jqgrid which describes issues with Oleg demo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very good point!

I personally prefer to use ondblClickRow event handler to start the editing mode. So you can use `oneditfunc` parameter of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow):

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e) {
    grid.jqGrid('editRow',rowid,true,function(){
        $("input, select",e.target).focus();
    });
    return;
}
```

or just place the like of code which set the focus after the call of `editRow`:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e) {
    grid.jqGrid('editRow',rowid,true);
    $("input, select",e.target).focus();
    return;
}
```

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingFocus.htm).

Comment: Thanks for you help. And another question, every column in the data source must have a name, right? I have seen it in the example.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, but it doesn't work, maybe I did something wrong, because it's still selecting the first column of the row. In my code, I have many jqgrids, and I should I need to use the name or the id of the grid to call the jquery function, right?

Comment: By the way, I'm creating my data on a controller in Json format, like this example: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: I have tested my code and it seems to work fine on chrome and firefox, but it doesn't with ie8. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Specter: If you has some problems with more as one grid you should verify that the grid data use different rowids. You can append your question with the code of the controller action which you use.

Comment: @Specter: You wrote that you have more as one grid on the page. Where is the controller for the second grid? By the way, I recommend you too look at UPDATED part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644)

Comment: the rest of the grids doesn't have any data, by now. I'm testing for only one grid with data.

Comment: @Specter: We spend many time without any results. So is my demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingFocus.htm work on your computer in all web browsers? If it is work and your code not work, then your problem could be only in the code which you use. So to be able to help you I need have the code. It is easier you you open new question, include the client and the server codes and describe exactly what is not work correct.

Comment: I  have solved my problem. I hadn't declared the beforeSelectRow function and I had declared a function on the event onSelectRow, so that was the problem. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Specter: You are welcome! If the end is good, everything is good.

Comment: This answer helped me on the spot. There is also a rather undocumented new focusField parameter that can be set on the editrow parameters that can be used that can be added to this answer. 
https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/e5a0baae4231df832ab92a9881ca9c027e6afdaf

Comment: @elpd: I know about the `focusField` parameter. If you read any **old answer** on the stackoverflow that you should understand that it describes the state at the time or writing the answer (about 4 years ago). You can't expect that one update all previous answers with the new information based on every new release of jqGrid. Even the update of the documentation is a problem because not all users uses the latest version. Moreover jqGrid is **free** and you can't expect that somebody invest a lot of his time in editing information for other. Which fork and which version of jqGrid you use now?

Comment: @Oleg Hi. First thanks for the answer. About the focusField, It was a suggestion, not expectation. I did not want to touch someone else correct answer so I just put it in the comment.

Comment: @elpd: You are welcome! Starting with the end of December 2014 I started my fork of jqGrid: [**free jqGrid**](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). I posted some [wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md). The owner of old documentation is Tony. I plan to start soon new documentation about free jqGrid. Both old documentation and free jqGrid wiki are **opened for all for writing**. So you can modify the text or add new article. Best wishes!