# How to avoid horizontal scroll on single click cell editing in free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Code below based in answer from [How to set focus to cell which was clicked to start inline edit in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219598/how-to-set-focus-to-cell-which-was-clicked-to-start-inline-edit-in-jqgrid)

is used to put focus to clicked cell to start inline editing of this cell in single click.

If jqgrid is wide so that horizontal scrollbar appears and rightmost column is clicked, jqgrid scrolls to leftmost column and after that it scrolls back to clicked column.

This causes unpleasant flashing visual effect.
How to remove this flashing ?

To reproduce, open page below in Chrome, scroll right and click in Amount column.
Grid flashes before editing starts.
How to remove this flashing ?

Is is possible to turn screen update off during this scroll, put all grid cells
to edit mode initially or other idea ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        /*global $,Modernizr */
        /*jslint browser: true, unparam: true */
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    { id: "10",  invdate: "", name: "test1",  note: "note1",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" }
                ],
                $grid = $("#list"),
                initDateEdit = function (elem, options) {
                    // we need get the value before changing the type
                    var orgValue = $(elem).val(), newformat,
                        cm = $(this).jqGrid("getColProp", options.name);

                    $(elem).attr("type", "date");
                    if ((Modernizr && !Modernizr.inputtypes.date) || $(elem).prop("type") !== "date") {
                        // if type="date" is not supported call jQuery UI datepicker
                        $(elem).css({ width: "8em" }).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "d.m.Y",
                            autoSize: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            showWeek: true
                        });
                    } else {
                        // convert date to ISO
                        if (orgValue !== "") {
                            //newformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.newformat ?
                            //    cm.formatoptions.newformat :
                            //    $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.newformat");
newformat="d.m.Y";
                            $(elem).val($.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, newformat, orgValue, "Y-m-d"));
                        }
                        // "10em" is better for Chrome and "11em" for Opera 24
                        $(elem).css("width", /OPR/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "11em" : "10em");
                    }
                },
                myBeforeSaveRow = function (options, rowid) {
                    var $self = $(this), $dates = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)).find("input[type=date]");
                    $dates.each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this), newformat, str,
                            id = $this.attr("id"),
                            colName = id.substr(rowid.length + 1),
                            cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", colName);
                        if ((Modernizr && Modernizr.inputtypes.date) || $this.prop("type") === "date") {
                            // convert from iso to newformat
                            str = $this.val();
                            if (str !== "") {
                                //newformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.newformat ?
                                //    cm.formatoptions.newformat :
                                //    $self.jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.newformat");
newformat="d.m.Y";

                                str = $.jgrid.parseDate.call($self[0], "Y-m-d", str, newformat);
                            }
                            $this.attr("type", "text");
                            $this.val(str);
                        }
                    });
                },
                initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                            autoSize: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showWeek: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true
                        });
                    }, 50);
                },
                numberTemplate = {formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
                    editrules: {number: true, required: true},
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"] }};

    function PutFocus(target) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            $("input, select",target).focus();
            $("input, select",target).select();
        },100);
      }


            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
//loadComplete: function() {
//    $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
//},
                data: mydata,
                colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes", "Tax", "Amount", "Total"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "name", align: "center", editable: true, width: 65, editrules: {required: true} },
                    { name: "invdate", width: 1625, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                        formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d.m.Y"}, editable: true,
                        editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
                    { name: "closed", width: 70, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "checkbox",
                        edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"},
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" } },
                    { name: "ship_via", width: 105, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "select",
                        edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
                    { name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea" },
                    { name: "tax", width: 52, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
                    { name: "amount", 

editable:true,"width":120,"classes":null,"hidden":false,
"editoptions":{"maxlength":60,"size":60}


/*, template: numberTemplate*/ },
                    { name: "total", width: 60, template: numberTemplate }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                pager: "#pager",
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                sortname: "invdate",
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                height: "auto",
                rownumbers: true,
                editurl: "clientArray",
//editurl: "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/test",
        toppager: true,



           beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                var $this = $(this), rows = this.rows,
                  // get id of the previous selected row
                  startId = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
                  startRow, endRow, iStart, iEnd, i, rowidIndex,
                  colName = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest('td')[0]),
               cmd = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                if (cmd[colName].name === 'cb' ) {
                    return true;
                }

    $this.jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
                PutFocus(e.target);
            },
            });

        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand the problem. `editRow` supports `focusField` option starting with jqGrid 4.7 (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:changetwo#jqgrid_4.7.0_changes_and_fixes)). It can be used in free jqGrid too. The value `focusField: false` will prevent setting of focus to the first editable column. You can in generally remove `PutFocus` function and replace it to `focusField: colName` (the name `colName` seems me not the best because it's more `iCol`), where the value of `focusField` should be the number of the column in the row.

Comment: Adding `$.extend(true,$.jgrid.inlineEdit, {focusField: false})` fixes the issue. Focus should set to and text selected in clicked column so static value cannot used. Is it possible to add `focusField: 'ClickedColumnAndSelect' ` setting for this to remove PutFocus?

Comment: @Andrus: You start editing inside of `beforeSelectRow`. `$.jgrid.getCellIndex` the the index of the clicked column. So, it seems to me, that you can just use the returned value as the option of `editRow`: `$this.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, {focusField: colName});` and remove the next line `PutFocus(e.target);`

Comment: Thank you. It does not select text in focused element.

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! I mean just that you can remove `$("input, select",target).focus();` from `PutFocus`. You can still use `$("input, select",target).select();`. In any way if you have *multiple* ways to solve the problem it's better as having unsolved problem. :-) You can choose yourself which way is the best for your environment.

Comment: @Oleg: I think I asked a question earlier. I got the answer here after few days. Thanks Oleg!!!

Comment: @SKumar: You are welcome! One can use `focusField` with **dynamic** value instead of specifying some static name of the column. [The demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ft7zsocy/), created for [the answer](`http://stackoverflow.com/a/40678830/315935`) uses `$(this).jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });`, where `focusField` will be get from the Event. As the result the focus will be set in the cell in which the user click (double-click).