# jQGrid : triple click needed to edit a cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In JQgrid : To Edit a cell (not in first column), I need 3 mouse click to focus a cell, can I do that in double click ?

Eg : If I want to edit 'desription' column in my grid I need 3 mouse click.
[image]

Comment: "triple click" ???!!! Please think about other people who read your question and try to formulate the text so that everybody understand what you did and what you need to implement. **Do you need to implement editing on "triple click" or you already wrote the program with such strange behavior, which you want to eliminate?** If the problem exists in your current code, then you should include the JavaScript code, which you use in the text of your question.

Comment: @Oleg  Question Edited

Comment: @Oleg please look into your demo from link : http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm there also you need 3 click to edit tax cell

Comment: I need double-click to start editing. The old my demo uses retro version of jqGrid 3.8.2. Later versions have options, which allows to customize the focus behavior by usage `focusField` option of `editRow`, which you calls in `ondblClickRow`. I can provide you the demo which uses [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and starts `editRow` inside of `ondblClickRow` saving previously editing row in `beforeSelectRow`. So there are no common problem in jqGrid with the requirement of additional setting focus on the double-clicked cell.

Comment: @Oleg can you give me a demo please? No problem if you are busy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use free jqGrid, then you can use You can use `focusField` option of `editRow`:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    $(this).jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });
},
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var $self = $(this), i,
        // savedRows array is not empty if some row is in inline editing mode
        savedRows = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
    for (i = 0; i < savedRows.length; i++) {
        if (savedRows[0].id !== rowid) {
            // save currently editing row
            // one can replace saveRow to restoreRow in the next line
            $self.jqGrid("saveRow", savedRows[i].id);
        }
    }
    return savedRows.length === 0; // allow selection if saving successful
},
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/ft7zsocy/

Comment: it is working, but on enter keypress after editing - row not saving before that form submission occurs. any idea ?

Comment: @thalla: It's just an option of `editRow`. You can modify `$(this).jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });` to `$(this).jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target, keys: true });` or to add `inlineEditing` option, which specify *default* options of inline editing, like `inlineEditing: { keys: true }`. See https://jsfiddle.net/ft7zsocy/1/

Comment: Thank you very much.there should an option for tagging Oleg :)