# Need jqGrid inline editing to have focus go to clicked cell

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Others have asked this question, but there's been no good answers that I can find.

- [No answer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/set-focus-to-first-editable-cell-in-row/)
- [Oleg punted to double clicking cells](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/set-focus-to-first-editable-cell-in-row/)

With a jqgrid and inline editing, is it possible to get the focus on the cell that was selected instead of the first cell on the row?  In an `onCellSelect` handler I can move the focus, but then it immediately returns to the first cell on the line.

Firebug consistently crashes as I step out of the `onCellSelect` callback so I haven't made much headway into the jqGrid source itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered on the close question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6538102/315935). If you use double-click to enter in the inline editing you can directly use my previous answer.

If you use selection of the row (`onSelectRow` callback) you will have problem to detect the cell which is clicked because the current version of jqGrid don't has the event object as the parameter. The last version of jqGrid on the [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) are already has the parameter (see [my suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/extending-onselectrow-with-additional-event-parameter/#p25534) and [the fix](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/3faa27050633b2a2897e485a921269281815d8c3)) and you can do the same inside `onSelectRow`.

If you do need to use released version jqGrid 4.3.1 and need to set focus in the `onSelectRow` callback you can use additionally `beforeSelectRow` callback to cache last `e.target` in a variable and uses it inside of `onSelectRow`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code (jqGrid 4.4.1)

```
 onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
   var setFocusToCell = function(e) {
     if(!e || !e.target) return;
     var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"), $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow"), ci, ri, rows = this.rows;
     if ($td.length === 0 || $tr.length === 0 || !rows) return;
     ci = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
     ri = $tr[0].rowIndex;
     $(rows[ri].cells[ci]).find("input,select").focus();
   }
   setFocusToCell(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow succeeded to accomplish this by attaching a dblclick event to every td of the table, I know this is not the best method, but you are free to optimize it how you like, you can also ignore the setTimeout which was used only for testing.

```
 $("#jqGrid").on("dblclick", "td", function (event) {   
                 //   setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log(this);
                        $(event.target).find("input,select").focus();                     
                  //  }, 0);
                });
```

Hope this will help you.