# jqgrid multiple datepickers and autofocus

Tags: jqgrid, datepicker

i think i found a strange bug in jqGrid.
If you click on [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/andreapier/yNw3C/2000/) you can see a jqGrid with a pager. If you click on the '+' button you get the add form in which the 2 datepickers work as expected.

If you now click on [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/andreapier/yNw3C/2001/) you can see the very same table, and the very same add button. Anyway if you try to set the second date using tha datepicker you will notice that the focus moves back to the first input, opening the first datepicker.
The example does not work because it has the first field (`Id`) hidden, so the real first field is a `datepicker`. Moreover, the edit form is modal.

Last, if you click in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/andreapier/yNw3C/2002/) the behaviour is correct even if the first field is a datepicker. The only thing i changed is the modal property (to false, before it was true).

However, i NEED to hide the `Id` field AND have a modal window, so i have to to get rid of this problem...
Can someone suggest a solution or an hint?
Thanks

PS: notice that if you set `modal: false`, you still get the black/transparent overlay like if the window is modal BUT it is not! If you click outisde the edit form it will be closed. This is not acceptable for my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set jqModal parameter into false

```
var editParams = {
     modal: true,
     jqModal:false,
     ... //other options you need
}

grid.editGridRow(row_id, editParams);
```

for more information see answer Oleg's [analisys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282798/315935)

Comment: This actually solves the problem! Thanks! However, i'm wondering if there are consequences in setting jqModal:false