# Trouble iterating through a basic JSON array of values

Tags: jquery, json

I'm embarrassed to ask but I'm really having trouble getting the values out of some JSON. I just can't seem to access the array of values correctly.

I can get the values from this Json (fiddle: [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqLy5upp/)) which uses the json response in the format below:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "tags": [
                "jqgrid"
            ],
            "owner": {
                "reputation": 21,
                "user_id": 3038042,
                "user_type": "registered",
                "accept_rate": 70,
                "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/819ef95bfca002204f5bd00654fb9957?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
                "display_name": "Amete",
                "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/3038042/amete"
            },
            "is_answered": false,
            "view_count": 5,
            "answer_count": 1,
            "score": 1,
            "last_activity_date": 1423648956,
            "creation_date": 1423605704,
            "last_edit_date": 1423648956,
            "question_id": 28442722,
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442722/jqgrid-set-focus-on-selectrow-not-working",
            "title": "JqGrid Set Focus on SelectRow not working"
        }
    ]
}
```

BUT I can't do the same for the Json below ([failed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am77Lm8w/))

```
[{
    "Manufacturer": "Toyota",
    "Sold": 1200,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "Ford",
    "Sold": 1100,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "BMW",
    "Sold": 900,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "Benz",
    "Sold": 600,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}]
```

I know I am not accessing the array correctly but everything I've tried has failed.

Additionally, it looks simpler to use the JQuery $.getJSON approach but I can't make that work either...

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The failed fiddle doesn't get any data, it's stopped by the same-origin policy

Comment: Of course... foolish of me... In reality I'm actually using a  web service - I just used the example JSON for simplicity. I thought the web service got around the whole 'same-origin policy' but, taking the approach of @TrueBlueAussie below I see that copying the data out of my service and declaring it as a variable works. This was the main reason I could not get any responses. Can you explain why the stackoverflow API doesn't suffer from the same-origin policy but my API does? http://goo.gl/m0SQB4 ?

Comment: OK. So ultimately I have been suffering from same-origin policy. This has made testing my APIs and utilising them locally (in dev) impossible. Ultimately I ended up enabling CORS on the server which resolved the issues below and enabled my tests using a real API work.

Comment: I'm using .NET and WebAPI so here's the article that resolved it for me: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second set of data is a pure array with no named element called `item` at the top level.

Use

```
var item = result[i];
```

not

```
var item = result.item[i];
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/am77Lm8w/3/

I turned your Ajax callback into an IIFE to test the data.

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie! That works well but I tried your approach with my real web service (rather than the example) and still got no data. I presume this is down to the same-origin policy restrictions but I thought web service API's got around that? The lack of data was the cause of my multiple failed attempts to get a result prevoiusly. Here's a working fiddle based on your approach here:  http://jsfiddle.net/yokmtpco/ Failed fiddle using the web service here: http://jsfiddle.net/qqxwuse0/. It's clear I must seriously up-skill here.

Comment: Both those JSFiddles look the same to me. Was the second one supposed to use a webservice?

Comment: Yes, thanks @TrueBlueAussie, it should have been. Odd... I had two open windows... both the same URL. It didn't update apologies. Here's the correct version http://jsfiddle.net/qqxwuse0/1/

Comment: That one has a missing `}` on the `success:` function. Good indenting is your friend :) http://jsfiddle.net/qqxwuse0/2/

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did think I'd better just check using JSHint but you were so fast you beat me to it. :) Still no response outputted though? Although there is when the JSON is declared as a variable...

Comment: If you check the console output you will see it is failing due to cross domain security. You will need to allow access to that server or start using JSONP..

Answer (score 0):

There is no `items` in your second json.

You need to use `var item = result[i];`

Comment: always check for exact duplicate answers before posting :)

Comment: i was writting as you posted and so does not display the answer only the notification

Comment: Thanks both. I appreciate all help. It's a kind gesture.